# Trouble with using argv elements

Tags: c, multithreading, argv

i need to take all the arguments in argv and use it for different porpuse, the program entry will be like this

```
./program -t <a number> -d <a string> -m < a char, e or l >
```

IE: `./program -t 10 -d have/a/nice/day -m e`

Im doing is this:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        int i,nt;
        char aux[6];


    for (i=0;i<6;i++){
        aux[i] = *((char*)argv[i+1]);
    }

    nt=(int)aux[1]-'0';
    printf("%d",nt);
    printf("%c",aux[1]);

    pthread_t threads[nt];
    if (aux[5]=='e'){

        printf("mode ejec\n");  
        /*for (i=0;i<nt;i++){
            pthread_create (&threads[i],NULL,(void *)operacion,NULL);   

        for (i=0;i<nt;i++){
            pthread_join (threads[i],NULL); 
        }
}*/

    }else if(aux[5]=='l'){

    printf("mode lib\n");

    }
    return 0;

}
```

but when i take any position in the argv only shows the first character/number of the parameters

in the example, it will show this:

```
[-,1,-,h,-,e]
```

how i can take all the elements?

sorry if i didnt explain so well... english is not my main language

Comment: Sine `aux` array is defined as `char`, `aux[i]` can hold only a single character. Not sure why you need it, since `argv` itself is already an array of strings that you can use directly.  See http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex10.html for more on arrays of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying items in `argv` to a `char` array. You need to have a `char *` array instead (if you really wanted to copy `argv` or you could use `argv` itself)

Also it doesn't seem right to accept the args to be passed in to your program in specific order. You should rather follow a pattern like iterating over all args and when you encounter an option (eg. `-m`) you pick the next item as the options value.

Answer (score 0):

Take a close look at that `for` loop. Remember, C-style strings are null-terminated char arrays. By dereferencing the pointer that `argv[i+1]` gives you, you are getting the first character of that string.

What different purpose would that be? Except for specific cases, you'd just read `argv` directly. But, if you really want to store it separately, you could do something like

```
char *aux[6];
for (i=0;i<6;i++){
    aux[i] = argv[i+1];
}
```

to work with the pointers in a different array. Or you could also do

```
char *aux[6];
for (i=0;i<6;i++){
    aux[i] = strdup(argv[i+1]);
}
```

to store copies of the arguments in that array (you'd need to `free` those afterwards, since `strdup` allocates memory for a new string). It's also okay to modify the strings pointed to by `argv`.

Finally, I'd suggest you to read about the `getopt` library ([1] and [2]), used to parse command-line options.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt
[2] https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html